# Horizontal scroll on click jQuery not working

Tags: jquery

I know there are many questions on this topic but even looking through them I could not figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have a website that scrolls horizontally, but I want users to also be able to click on a button to scroll right/left instead of only being able to do that through the scrollbar.

So this is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="mydiv">

    <?php foreach($page->children() as $subpage): ?>
      <div class="<?= $subpage->tags() ?>">
        <a href="<?= $subpage->url() ?>">
          <h2><?= html($subpage->title()) ?> </h2>
        </a>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>

    <div class="right-arrow">
        <a href="">
          <img src="/assets/images/arrow-right.svg"

                  width="100"
                  border="0">
          </a>
      </div>

  </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".right-arrow").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $('body').scrollLeft(1000);
      });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is body element the one that is being scrolled (the one that has the scrollbar)?

Comment: no it's .mydiv, but that doesn't work either

Comment: `right-arrow` <=> `arrow-right` how should that ever work?

Comment: dumb mistake - my bad. However, it still doesn't work after fixing that

Comment: hi you are not wrong .
But the left value is more .So I think it always left side of the page

Comment: @LDS what do you mean?

Comment: hi it alwayes go to left .in if condition change the value of scrollLeft argument dynamically and try to pass by variable with negative value so it go to right

Comment: I don't understand, can you give me an example?